# CSS style in JavaFX not working next to comment

Tags: css, javafx

I have a CSS style sheet used to style a clickable image, the class btnDefault is the one that is not working. The style sheet grew in size, so I began commenting the stylesheet. Long story short, this works:

```
.charPaneSmallText
{
    -fx-font-size: 24;
    -fx-text-fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.btnDefault
{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 0 0;

    -fx-border-width: 0;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-radius: 5 5 5 5;
}
```

this does not:

```
.charPaneSmallText
{
    -fx-font-size: 24;
    -fx-text-fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  style classes for the +/- image buttons in the tree elements  //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
.btnDefault
{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-radius: 0 0 0 0;

    -fx-border-width: 0;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-radius: 5 5 5 5;
}
```

All style classes after btnDefault work regardless of if the block comment is in place or not.

Am I doing something silly here?

Thanks,
-Will

Comment: You have an extra `/` at the end of the comment... not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @James_D No he doesn't; CSS comments are `/* */`

Comment: @guyfleeman By the way, for non-zero values in CSS, units are required (`px` or `em` or `%`, etc.). Try adding `px` to each instance of `5` in `-fx-border-radius`.

Comment: @TylerH good to know! I will add them. thanks.

Comment: In JavaFX, the [CSS docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typesize) explicitly state that "If units are not specified then specified the 'px' is assumed." (sic; I think you get what they meant). However, it is good practice to include them.

Comment: @TylerH I agree completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing around for a while, I found that it only worked when a spaces were placed as follows:

```
/* /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  style classes for the +/- image buttons in the tree elements  //
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */
```

I had been writing CSS block comments like in my question for webdev but it looks like the JavaFX CSS parser can't handle them without the spaces.

Is this a bug or is it documented as such, I could not find anything?

Comment: Create a [bug report in the JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).